# Element is not declared validation error post upgrading from .Net v4.5 to .Net v4.5.2

Tags: c#, .net, xml, dtd

I understand that there are already many existing threads for the 'element not found' error for XML validation but I'm posting this as my problem is slightly different.

My code was running fine until it was on .Net v4.5. After upgrading the framework to v4.6.1, I started getting this error for each XML element in my xml file. Upon downgrading I found that the error started occurring from .Net framework v4.5.2 onwards. Below is my code:

**XML** - Book.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<!DOCTYPE book SYSTEM "Book.dtd">
<book>
    <title>The Lord of the Rings</title>
    <author>J.R.R. Tolkien</author>
    <isbn>1572810556</isbn>
</book>
```

**DTD** - Book.dtd

```
<!ELEMENT book (title, author, isbn)>
<!ELEMENT title (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT author (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT isbn (#PCDATA)>
```

**C# Functions**

```
public static void ReadXMLwithDTD()
{
    // Set the validation settings.
    XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
    settings.ValidationType = ValidationType.DTD;
    settings.DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Parse;
    settings.ValidationEventHandler += new ValidationEventHandler(ValidationCallBack);
    settings.IgnoreWhitespace = true;

    // Create the XmlReader object.
    XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create("Book.xml", settings);

    // Parse the file.
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}: {2} ", reader.NodeType, reader.Name, reader.Value);
    }
}

private static void ValidationCallBack(object sender, ValidationEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Severity == XmlSeverityType.Warning)
        Console.WriteLine("Warning: Matching schema not found.  No validation occurred." + e.Message);
    else // Error
        Console.WriteLine("Validation error: " + e.Message);
}
```

When run the code the callback throws validation errors (element not found) for all four XML elements - book, title, author and isbn.

Any help to fix this will be appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: Delete bin folder in project so code get rebuilt.  When upgrading Net Library dependencies aren't recognized by compiler.  So simple solution is to delete bin folder which will force everything to recompile.

Comment: Tried that, same result. Thanks.

Comment: Try changing the settings to see if it makes a difference?  How are you generating xml?  Is it with similar code?  Are you using same xml when it works and not work?  Is schema built into xml file?

Comment: What settings shall I change? The XML are static files for now. Yes, the same XML and DTD work with v4.5 but not v4.5.2 onwards. The schema is defined in the DTD as detailed above.

Comment: Have you confirmed that the DTD is being read at all?  If you introduce a syntax error into it, does the error message change?

Comment: It seems the DTD is not read. I introduced errors, even renamed the file, there was no change. Next, I reverted the errors and switched the framework back to 4.5, the code worked as expected. With the framework still set at 4.5, I re-introduced the errors and the code threw errors as applicable. Thanks.

Comment: So, I've found a workaround for this issue by embedding the DTD in the XML file for now. Using the below XML with the initial code does not result in any validation errors.

    <?xml version="1.0" ?>
    <!DOCTYPE book [
     <!ELEMENT book (title, author, isbn)>
     <!ELEMENT title (#PCDATA)>
     <!ELEMENT author (#PCDATA)>
     <!ELEMENT isbn (#PCDATA)>
    ]>
    <book>
     <title>The Lord of the Rings</title>
     <author>J.R.R. Tolkien</author>
     <isbn>1572810556</isbn>
    </book>

Answer (score 3):

I'm a bit late to the party but I think I've found a solution by adding the following code right before
*settings.ValidationEventHandler += new ValidationEventHandler(ValidationCallBack);*

```
settings.XmlResolver = new XmlUrlResolver();
```

Starting with the .NET Framework 4.5.2, this setting has a default value of null.

Reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreadersettings.xmlresolver(v=vs.110).aspx